# C++ - passing smart pointer derived class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, smart-pointers

I have a class `Character` that inherits from a base class `CollidableObject`. `CollidableObject` has, as you may have guessed, methods to detect collisions between other `CollidableObject`s, such as `CircleCollidableObject` and `SquareCollidableObject`.

```
bool CollidableObject::collidesWith(std::shared_ptr<CollidableObject> &pCollidable)
{
    ...
}
```

I use this to run other checks, and eventually handle the collision. Basically I want to be able to loop through the characters in my game, pass in two `Character`s (that, again, inherit from `CollidableObject`), and detect any collisions.

```
void CharacterManager::collisions()
{
    for(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Character>>::iterator i = mCharacters_.begin(); i != mCharacters_.end(); i++) {
        for(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Character>>::iterator j = mCharacters_.begin(); j != mCharacters_.end(); j++) {
            if(i == j) continue;
            (*i)->collidesWith(*j);
   ...
}
```

I'd rather not make the `mCharacters_` vector into a vector of `CollidableObjects` if I dont have to. But I'm not sure if that's the only way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you rewrite the interface? There's nothing wrong with having:

```
bool CollidableObject::collidesWith(const CollidableObject* pCollidable)
```

Presumably `collidesWith` isn't going to take ownership of the pointer you pass in, so passing in a raw pointer is fine.

That said, `shared_ptr<CollidableObject>` is actually constructible from `shared_ptr<Character>`. So if you want to take a `shared_ptr`, you'll have to take it by *const* reference instead of by reference. That is:

```
bool CollidableObject::collidesWith(const std::shared_ptr<CollidableObject>& p)
```

or just by-value:

```
bool CollidableObject::collidesWith(std::shared_ptr<CollidableObject> p)
```

See constructor #9 from [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr).

And if you're using `std::shared_ptr`, you should at least use `auto` in your loops to reduce the verbosity. And the `j` loop can start one-past `i` to avoid double-checking every pair:

```
for (auto i = mCharacters_.begin(); i != mCharacters_.end(); ++i) {
    for (auto j = std::next(i); j != mCharacters_.end(); ++j) {
        (*i)->collidesWith(j->get());
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this. And I didn't know about next, so thanks for that.

Comment: `bool CollidableObject::collidesWith(const CollidableObject&)` would be my signature of choice.

Comment: Changing the smart pointer to raw makes inherited methods and members unavailable for some reason. Any idea?